# C: Creating and returning a variable in a macro

Tags: c, macros, comma-operator

I'm a bit confused as to why this C macro fails to compile:

```
#define LUA_GET_FIELD(Lua, idx, name, type) (\
    lua_getfield((Lua), (idx), (name)), \
    typeof(lua_to##type) __result = lua_to##type((Lua), -1), \
    lua_pop((Lua), 1), __result)
```

When invoking it, I get errors:

```
src/event.lcpp.c:134:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘typeof’
src/event.lcpp.c:134:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘typeof’
```

The same happens if I replace `typeof(lua_to##type)` with just `int`, so I suspect the issue is to do with the commas. Can you not declare variables in the middle of an expression like this?

I know gcc has an extension for returning values from blocks, but I want to avoid compiler extensions. I also realize this should be changed to an inline function, but now I'm curious why the macro doesn't work.

Comment: The expression `typeof(lua_to##type)` evaluates to a function type, not the type that the `lua_to##type` function returns.

Comment: "I want to avoid compiler extensions" - `typeof` is a compiler extension, so if you're willing to use that, it might not be too bad to take the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C indeed does not allow you to arbitrarily define new variables inside expressions.  Older standards didn't even allow them anywhere but at the start of a block (that is, you couldn't intermix them with statements either).

Comment: `typeof` is a GCC extension too (unless that's been added to C11).

Comment: @Mat: Isn't `typeof` in C going against the language? As it is not strong typing. The concept of types is a bit different in comparison to most other languages.